# Get channel/guild name by its id with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to retrieve the channel name, users list from a specific channel by its ID.

I'm getting the error `Missing access`

Error message:

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\BattlefyParser\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (c:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\BattlefyParser\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildManager.fetch (c:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\BattlefyParser\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildManager.js:247:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/guilds/810614721694007316?with_counts=true',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

My code:

```js
const channelID = "810614721694007316";

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    client.guilds
        .fetch(channelID)
        .then((guild) => console.log(guild.name))
        .catch(console.error);
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is missing the required permissions to perform that action. Make sure it has the `View Channels` permission when generating the OAuth2 token in the [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) panel.